# Ambiguous use of variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I converted my Swift to the `current Swift syntax` and now get the following error in this code:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0] as AnyObject
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(saveFileName)
```

Error: `Ambiguous use of appendingPathComponent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically

- never cast a type up to something more unspecific.
- never cast a distinct known type at all.

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns clearly `[String]`, so delete the annotation and the cast.

```
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
```

However it's recommended to use the URL related API because in Swift 3 the path functions in `String` have been removed.

```
let documentsDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let dataURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(saveFileName)
```

If you really need the string path add

```
let dataPath = dataURL.path
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get the following error: `appendingPathComponent is unavailable: Use appendingPathComponent on URL instead`

Comment: Works like a charm!